# Convert JSON from Rest Service to an Array

Tags: jquery, json, data-binding

I have a problem in binding JSON data to KENDO Pie Chart. 
I have a service that return me JSON data from server and URL of my Service is as follow

url: "/DomainService/CompanyProfileDomainService.svc/json/GetCompanyProfileContactedViews"

when i paste this link in the firefox i get the following JSON data

```
{"GetContactedChartViewsResult":{"TotalCount":3,"RootResults":[
{"ContactedID":1,"ContactedName":"No","Occurances":5},
{"ContactedID":2,"ContactedName":"Under Consideration","Occurances":1},
{"ContactedID":3,"ContactedName":"Follow Up","Occurances":11}]}}
```

I only need "Occurances" from JSON and I am really struggling how to get it.

One option in my mind is to make an array in which i can inject all the "Occurances" and than bind that array to the Pie Chart but i dont know how to make this array from JSON as i am very much new to the JQuery.

Could please anyone help me to get me problem sorted. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate an array using JQuery I would use [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to retrieve the data then use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the object array.  After the asynch operation has completed arrayOfValues should contain all the occurances.

```
    var url = '/DomainService/CompanyProfileDomainService.svc/json/GetCompanyProfileContactedViews';
    var arrayOfValues = [];
    $.get(link, function (ajaxData) {

        $.each(ajaxData.GetContactedChartViewsResult.RootResults, function (i, v) {
            arrayOfValues[i] = v.Occurances;
        });
        alert(arrayOfValues.length); // proves the length of the array. 
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much AlexC. This work absolutly fine. Really appriciate your time and help. Thank You! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.GetContactedChartViewsResult.TotalCount; i++) {
   alert(data.GetContactedChartViewsResult.RootResults[i].Occurances);
}
```

You should be able to iterate that way :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much everyone. I tried AlexC code and it works absolutly fine. Thank you very very much for all of your help. Really Appriciate that. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `result` holds that object, you would access it like this: `result.GetContactedChartViewsResult.RootResults[0].Occurances`